# Ubuntu 14.04-Wired networks takes over 30 minutes to connect at work network and over couple of minutes at home network

Tags: networking, 14.04, wired

I am using ubuntu gnome 14.04. My question is closely related to following question on Askubuntu:

[wired-network-takes-too-much-time-to-establish-connection-after-wake-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464929/wired-network-takes-too-much-time-to-establish-connection-after-wake-up)

In addition to taking long time to connect to wired network after wake up, I am facing trouble with connecting to my work network. It keeps trying to acquire network connection for long time (sometimes even more than 45 minutes) and then suddenly connects. At home it starts with 192.... IP address but then restarting network solves the problem. But restarting network, even rebooting computer doesn't help while trying to connect to work network.

I looked into the syslog (after reading other question) and see that it keeps sending

```
DHCPREQUEST of "my home dynamic IP address" on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4f216654)
```

And finally after long long time it gets

```
DHCPNAK from "my work dynamic IP address"
```

After which wired network start working.

I am just a user and do not understand what these entries mean. But does this mean that when I shut down my laptop at home the network manager does not release the home IP address?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Today it seemed like it connected after 8 minutes (got IP address) but then Internet didn't work. On restarting network it didn't acquire IP address again. I logged out and logged back in using Unity session instead of Gnome and to my surprise everything seemed to be working seamlessly. So I revert back to Gnome and networking was okay. I rebooted the computer and it still works fine. I'll have to repeat this tomorrow to check if logging into Unity (from the beginning) shows networking issue or not.

Comment: Logging into Unity session from beginning took 7 minutes to acquire  IP address (connect) to work network. I know this can not be gnome issue because my office-mate can connect to work network (Ethernet) without issues but then he used only wireless connection to connect to his home network since installing Ubuntu 14.04. Is anyone else facing same issue?

Comment: I have switched to Unity finally and so far I am not facing any issues with wired connections at both home and work. I haven't tried logging into gnome session after that. It seemed to be an issue with handling two Ethernet connections and I have no idea why Unity handled it better than Gnome.